# unexpected extensions listed in system status

Tags: extension

Anyone any idea why I have the following extensions listed in System Status as being up-to-date in addition to the ones I expect?

```
Contribution cancel actions: Version 1.0
Event Cart: Version 1.0
Financial ACLs: Version 1.0
Theme: Greenwich: Version 1.0
Sequential credit notes: Version 1.0
```

I haven't knowingly installed them. They aren't listed under System Settings > Extensions and there is nothing for them in the uploads/civicrm/ext directory. I have cloned the site, updated from 5.26.2 to 5.33.1, updated UK Gift Aid extension and installed (and now uninstalled to check) Civirules extension. Before I re-run the process (to find out if I have done anything stupid by mistake, I wonder if anyone else has seen anything like this. Not event sure what some of them are.

I'm on WordPress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple versions ago the concept of "hidden" extensions was introduced. The theory was it would allow for moving bits of code out of core and into extensions without anyone noticing any difference at first, and then at some point make them visible/optional. You'll find them in the civicrm_extensions database table and also in the `ext` folder in the root of your civicrm folder.

So technically those are all still officially part of core right now, just the code has been rearranged.

Comment: Thanks - at least there is nothing to worry about. Still find it odd that it shows in the status. Also the idea of an event cart looks interesting, but I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: The latest docs seem to be at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/event/-/wikis/event-cart. The way to turn it on is at Admin - CiviEvent - CiviEvent component settings. When it becomes a real extension you would just enable the extension like any other addon.